# Raspberry PI + MotionPi and sensors

Tags: raspbian, camera

I've been using the MotionPi distribution for a little while to turn my Pi Model A into a security Cam. It works awesome. Prior to discovering this disto I was using rasbian and the Python Picamera API, it was excellent for tinkering. and I had it reading from my DS18B20 Digital temp sensor and pasting the results on the camera stills.

I've love this feature with MotionPi, does anyone have an idea how I might implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own question!
The motion software used by MotionPie listens on a control port. It's possible to send a wget command with a specific URL that will update the left text field with provided variables. I simply read the temperature sensor and then have the wget run every 5minutes.

```
http://username:password@localhost:7999/1/config/set?text_left=temp:$TEMPERATURE
```